# Is it possible to echo num rows (Integer) as decimal?

Tags: php

I want to do something as echo Integer but show it as decimal number..

In this case $rows[0] = 9

but I need to display it as 0.09 is that possible??

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "") or die("not connected");

$mydb = mysqli_select_db($con, "ehh") or die("no db found");


if(!$con){
die('dont connect '. mysqli_connect_error());
}


if(!$mydb){
die('dont connect '. mysqli_connect_error());
}



$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ohh";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$yeah = $rows[0];


echo $yeah;

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: simple mathematics `echo $yeah / 100;`

Answer (score 2):

Generic ( number with N digits )

```
$number = $rows[0];
$lenght = strlen($number);
$extra_decimals = 1; 
$divisor = str_pad('1',$lenght + $extra_decimals ,'0',STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$result = $number / intval($divisor);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL

```
select ( count(*)/100.0 ) from ohh
```

Or in PHP (not both at the same time)

```
echo $yeah / 100;
```